# pjsip for Android

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, pjsip

Does anyone have any experience with pjsip on android devices? I see several non-commercial/test projects using it, so I'm assuming it can be done, but none of them are well documented. I thought a good place to start would be the pjsip-jni project, but there's basically no documentation (that I've found, at least). I think I'm going to just try and dig into pjsip-jni and the android ndk and see where it gets me, but if anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pjsip works on Android, especially the 2.3 onwards as it has better multimedia API. Here is a link for links to csipsimple and a patch provided on the list:

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

Comment: Yeah, this was the route we went. PJSIP largely based on CSipSimple. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I have tried this but doesn't got success.......if any one of you have successfully build apjsua sample app then please help me.

Comment: Hey can you provide me the basic android studio project with pjsip imported. I have trying to make to work for a long time. But with no luck. Please help.